# IOS Segmented Control: Can't Change Selected Segment

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I created a segmented control in my storyboard that looks like this:

[image]

Then I created an IBAction for when the control's value changes:

```
@IBAction func segmentValChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    print("touched")
    if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        sender.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
    }
    else{
        sender.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

The only issue is that this function is never called!
When I click the Jokes (Beta) button, nothing happens.

However, when I created an IBOutlet for the control and tried to change the selected segment in my `viewDidLoad()`, it worked:

```
segmentedController.selectedSegmentIndex = 1
```

I know I probably missed something obvious, since I've never used a segmented control before.
Thanks so much if anyone can point out what this is.
Cheers!

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var currentImage: CurrentImage!

    var parameters: Parameters!

    @IBOutlet weak var segmentedController: UISegmentedControl!


    @IBAction func segmentValChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        print("touched")
        if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) { // switch to 1
            sender.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
        }
        else{
            sender.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        segmentedController.selectedSegmentIndex = 1
        self.segmentedController.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segmentValChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    }
}
```

And this is what it looks like when I right click the view:
[image]

Comment: Did you **tie** this function in IB to `.valueChanged`?

Comment: Yeah, I did this

Comment: The cosole is printing the ¨touched¨ message?

Comment: To clarify: the touched message is not being printed

Comment: So this function is not being called at all. I'm wondering if there's anything else I need to do (other than ctrl-drag the controller to the swift file and create an action), in order to get the segmented control to work?

Comment: Try add the action programatically, try in your viewDidLoad         `self.segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(change), for: .valueChanged)`

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work either. The colors still aren't switching on the controller, and nothing is printing to the console.

Comment: I agree with @ReinierMelian - to me it "sounds" like you've successfully "tied" (my verbiage) things in IB but the results say otherwise. First try the `addTarget` as suggested. If that works, you've proven that the issue is with the `@IBAction` connection, which looks good to me.

Comment: You might have something else wrong with doing `addTarget` - for that you need an `@IBOutlet`.

Comment: @JamesDorfman please post all your VC code, to see if there is something else that can cause this issue

Comment: I posted the code. The whole code involves a lot of app-specific code and stuff to get the camera working, so I removed it in order to improve readability.

Comment: I also posted an image to show what is going on with the view in the storyboard

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whenever I see this it is almost always the same problem... If the segmented control is being drawn *outside* of its parent view, then it will not respond to taps. This is most likely the problem you are having. (This can also happen with UIButtons.)

Ways to test if this is the problem:

1. set `clipsToBounds` of the segmented control's parent to true. If the control no longer shows on the screen, then it is being drawn outside of it's parent view. `segmentedControl.superview?.clipsToBounds = true`
2. add a border to the segmented control's parent. If the control is being drawn outside the border then there you go. `segmentedControl.superview?.layer.borderWidth = 1`

Solve the problem by expanding the size of the parent view so the control is being drawn within it.

---

On a side note, your IBAction is incorrect. When the value changed action is called, the segmented control will *already* have changed its value and the new segment will be highlighted. You don't have to do it manually. This is another indicator that your control isn't being drawn in the bounds of its parent view.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. This answer worked perfectly.

Comment: I just had the same issue occur. I added both lines Daniel T. suggested and it still doesn't respond..

Comment: Another possibility is that one of the views in the superView hierarchy has its `isUserInteractionEnabled` set to false.