# unable to select first index of UISegmentedControl Swift

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I have supplied target to the segmentControl by but when ever i click the second index it displays fine but the first index when clicked show nothing.

```
cell.segmentControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segmentValueDidChanged(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)

@objc func segmentValueDidChanged(sender : UISegmentedControl){
        
        if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0{
            self.type = 0
        }else{
              self.type = 1
        }
}
```

`segmentValueDidChanged` is never called when index first is selected

Comment: You can check this out if you didn't yet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45068772/ios-segmented-control-cant-change-selected-segment

Comment: thanks I have tried this nothing is out of bound